# Converting int8_t to int, so I can perform operations on it

Tags: c++, char, int

I am working on a code that has to perform a series of operations on an array of `int8_t`, where each element has a number stored, ranging from 0 to 255.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int8_t v = ...  // Imagine it's an array equal to {1, 10, 100, 255}.
    int y[4];
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        y[i] = v[i]*3;

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm looking for is either a way to make operations with the `int8_t` array, or preferably a way to convert `int8_t` into `int`s (I have a big code which works with `int` inputs, converting `int8_t` to `int` and then giving it to my code would require less changes than changing every `int` to `int8_t`).

It may also be worth noting that the `int8_t` array comes from a video capture of a camera, which returns the value of each pixel from 0 to 255 in `int8_t` form, which means I can't change the input array.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

### Edit:

Dummy code, which hopefully will help illustrate my problem.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int8_t v[4] = {'0','1','2','3'};

    int y;

    y = (int) v[1]*3;

    std::cout << v[1] << "  " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output I get when I run this is  `1 49`.

Comment: Why not just cast it: `y[i] = ((int)v[i])*3;`

Comment: That's the same as his code but uglier  (`v[i]` implicitly converts to `int` when used in arithmetic)

Comment: @Daniel, your code is mostly fine as written, can you clarify what problem you are having?  I say "mostly" because `255` is out of range for `int8_t`. Either use `uint8_t` or change `255` to something else such as `-1`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb  Yes, sorry. I use uint8_t in the actual code. I've been trying to fix this problem with a test code, where I simply used int8_t, since I used values lower than 10.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Can you give an example of the function that "takes int inputs" that is difficult to use with `v` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb My problem is that I can't make operations on the int8_t values. If I can do the basic operations (multiply, divide, add and subtract) my problem will be solved. This led me to wonder if there was anyway to convert them to ints, so I can operate on them normally.

Comment: There is no difference in the operations that you can perform. There is a difference in what is stored after the operation if your operation overflows. Can you please give us an example of the values that you are trying to multiply? **Exact** inputs that illustrate the problem, what **outputs** were given and what outputs you **expected**.

Comment: @user2961736 but you *can* do math on int8_t values. If you get a compile error when you try, then you'd better post it. Also, include the initialization of v and how you are printing the answer, as it is possible to have errors there.

Comment: They automatically convert to ints when you use them.  `uint8_t a = 5, b = 6;  foo(a + b);`

Comment: I'm starting to think, because of your answers, that maybe my error is in the printing of the numbers. Anyway, I've added a dummy code which hopefully will be helpful. I get no compiling errors @GeoffReedy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latest edit is incorrectly initializing the array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int8_t v[4] = {'0','1','2','3'}; // <- This is wrong!

    int y;

    y = (int) v[1]*3;

    std::cout << v[1] << "  " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Numbers in **single quotes** are [**ASCII characters**](http://www.asciitable.com/) whose numeric values *don't match the actual number in the quotes*.

Please modify your code like this and see if it helps:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int8_t v[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3}; // <- Remove the single quotes

    int y;

    y = (int) v[1]*3;

    std::cout << v[1] << "  " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is a link to [ideone](http://ideone.com/U1oDQJ)

**Follow up question (from comments):**

> I never declare the actual array, I import it directly from a .txt file. When I do this I get the same result as if I had declared it with the quotes. Is there a way to work around this, converting it from ascii code to the desired numeric value?

Yes. You can use the [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) or [stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) functions to convert a number that is represented as text to an integer. You should also take a look at [this link](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/) discussing how to use stream operators to achieve the same.

However, converting the numbers from strings is pretty easy so I'll give you an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int getNumberFromString(const char* numberString)
{
    int number = 0;
    int i;
    int stringLength = strlen(numberString);

    for (i = 0; i < stringLength; ++i)
    {
        number *= 10;
        number += numberString[i] - '0';
    }

    return number;
}

int main()
{
    const char* numberSeventyNineString = "79"; // Equivalent to { '7', '9', '\0' }
    int numberSeventyNine;

    numberSeventyNine = getNumberFromString(numberSeventyNineString);

    std::cout << "Number (" << numberSeventyNineString << ") as int is: " << numberSeventyNine << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the [ideone link](http://ideone.com/czB6v1)

***Note:*** The line `const char* numberSeventyNineString = "79"; // Equivalent to { '7', '9', '\0' }` has a comment saying that this is equivalent to an array, for a little more detail please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951919/how-to-concatenate-a-char-array-case-0-and-1-to-a-char-pointer-in-c/22952162#22952162)

Comment: It worked! I have a problem tho. In reality I never declare the actual array, I import it directly from a .txt file. When I do this I get the   same result as if I had declared it with the quotes. Is there a way to work around this, converting it from ascii code to the desired numeric value?

Comment: Yes, you need to convert the *ASCII* characters to integers. There is a C library function that does this **atoi** but the algorithm is pretty simple. Also, since this is C++ have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/D9j2Nwbp/

Comment: In fact I'll add an example to my answer to make it simple.

Answer (score 2):

In C/C++ types that are less than int are automatically promoted to int. But `int8_t` is a signed type so it **cannot store values such as 255** in your first snippet

For the second snippet

```
int8_t v[4] = {'0','1','2','3'};
```

`'0' = 0x30 = 48` because that's its ASCII value, so multiplying it by 3 will not result in 0 like you expected

To convert a char value to its numeric value just subtract `'0'` from it, like `v[i] - '0'`